# Tile rendering problem in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering, isometric, tiled

I'm making an isometric game using a Tiled map with libgdx. As I want my character to be rendered before or after the tiles depending his positions, I create an `ArrayList<Renderable>` and I add in it my character and the tiles.

```
    TiledMapTileLayer midlayer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(4); //The layer containing my tiles.
    int width = midlayer.getWidth();
    int height = midlayer.getHeight();
    ArrayList<Renderable> renderables = new ArrayList<Renderable>();
    renderables.add(character); //Adding the character in the list;

    //We add to the list every midlayer's tile, so we can later sort
    for (int i=0;i<width;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<height;j++) {
            if (midlayer.getCell(i, j)!=null) { //As the cell can or can't exist in that position.
                renderables.add(new RenderableTile(midlayer.getCell(i, j).getTile().getTextureRegion(),i,j));
            }
        }
```

RenderableTile is a class I created containing a x and y position and the TextureRegion.

```
public class RenderableTile implements Renderable, Comparable<Renderable> {

private int x;
private int y;
private TextureRegion texture;

public RenderableTile(TextureRegion text, int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.texture = texture;
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch batch, BitmapFont font) {
    batch.begin();
    int rX = Translations.TransX(x, y);  //Transformation orthogonal position to isometric rendering
    int rY = Translations.TransY(x, y)-15;
    batch.draw(text, rX, rY);
    batch.end();
}
```

The sorting works perfectly, and the ArrayList seems containing the right tiles. But when I render I get this:

[image: In-game screenshot, tiles doesn't render fine.]

Instead of something like this:

[image: Tiled editor screenshot, how the map should look.]

This is really akward, when I try to render a single tile in a specific point it works normally.

Maybe there is an alternative solution?